# Comparing cells in Excel and adding blank rows above if they are not similar

Tags: vba, excel

I receive a daily list of many work shift times, usually formatted as per the following:

```
0800-2000
0800-2000
0801-2000
0930-2130
0930-2200
1000-2200
```

and so on... (each on a different row, hundreds at a time)

I'm trying to write a macro/VBA that groups each START time by inserting a blank row above each different start time (ignoring those that are only 1 minute apart, these are to be considered the same).

The concept I've thought of is to truncate the cell to take only the first 4 numbers using a LEFT(A3,4)+0 to convert back to integer. Dim 2 variables as Integers, Value1 being from the first row and Value2 being from the row below. Then run an IF statement where If Value2 - Value 1 > 2 THEN insert a blank row (EntireRow.Insert Shift = xlDown i think is the code, please correct if wrong).

Then i just need to repeat for the whole column until there are no more shift start times to separate. I was thinking of something along the line of either 'do until ISNUMBER = FALSE' or i could just run the macro for a predefined number of rows that i know will always be more than enough.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It's always good to see someone showing interest in learning the basics of coding, and doing some research!  Stack Overflow isn't really a "free code writing service", it's more of a place that developers (of any experience level) can bring a specific question about a specific issue, share their existing code and explain (as best as possible) what's been tried so far, where's been researched so far, along with examples of what they have and what they "need to have".  This makes the site useful to anyone else who is having a similar issue.

Comment: ...Better than me explaining would be to check out the [tour] as well as handy tips at [ask] and [mcve].  Have you checked for similar articles on Stack Overflow?  Here is another search to get you started.  If you need a crash course in VBA or Excel, there are some excellent tutorials and other resources just a search away.  Do you have a question about a ***specific*** problem, and some examples of what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

This short macro will do what you want:

```
Sub insert()
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, t1 As String, t2 As String

    n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = n To 2 Step -1
        t1 = Split(Cells(i, 1), "-")(0)
        t2 = Split(Cells(i - 1, 1), "-")(0)
        If t1 <> t2 Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.insert
    Next i
End Sub
```

The result:

[image]